# (Symfony 4) Unable to inject a github library that I installed with composer

Tags: symfony, dependencies, autowired, code-injection

I installed the following library from GitHub: https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert

The location of the main class that I need to is (from project root) :

```
\vendor\rosell-dk\webp-convert\src\WebPConvert.php
```

Here is how the WebPConvert.php class starts out:

```
namespace WebPConvert;

use WebPConvert\Converters\ConverterHelper;
use WebPConvert\ServeExistingOrConvert;
use WebPConvert\Serve\ServeExistingOrHandOver;

class WebPConvert
{
```

In the repository class where I use it, here is how I tried to do my dependency injection:

```
use WebPConvert\WebPConvert;

class PhotoRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{

    /**
     * @var WebPConvert
     */
    protected $webPConverter;

    public function __construct(WebPConvert $webPConverter)
    {
        $this->webPConverter = $webPConverter;
    }
```

I followed the instructions from https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

But I still get this message:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\PhotoRepository": argument "$webPConverter" of method "__construct()" references class "WebPConvert\WebPConvert" but no such service exists.
```

I have even tried putting this in my services.yaml and it doesn't work:

```
App\Repository\PhotoRepository:
    arguments:
        - WebPConvert\WebPConvert
```

Is there an extra step I am missing?

Comment: WebPConvert is not a Symfony bundle so it won't have any services defined. You will have to define them manually.  Actually, from the readme file, it looks like WebPConvert::convert is a static method so there is nothing to inject.  Just follow the example.

Comment: Thanks Cerad, that works.  Much apprecaited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Cerad's answer which worked:

WebPConvert is not a Symfony bundle so it won't have any services defined. You will have to define them manually. Actually, from the readme file, it looks like WebPConvert::convert is a static method so there is nothing to inject. Just follow the example.